# IE Select Checkbox When Image is Clicked

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am working on a form for a company that still uses tables and they want me to add CSS to their template without changing any HTML/JS.  There is a nested input(CheckBox) that should be selected when a user clicks the image.  This is working fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge but in IE when the image is clicked it will not check the box.  Below is a screen cap of the DOM and an actual choice in the browser.[image]

[image]

I changed the background color of the font tag to distinguish it from the image and added a border around the td. I noticed 2 strange things.

1. When the font tag is clicked it will check the box.
2. When the box is checked, I am able to click the image and have the checkbox 
   de-selected.  Once it is, I can not re-select it by clicking the image.

Any idea of what is causing this and what can be done?  I am using IE 11.

Comment: 2 inputs are wrapped into a single label , this is enough to mess up  the browser behavior.

Comment: @G-Cyr. I suggest you re-read [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element). *"If the `for` attribute is not specified, but the label element has a labelable element descendant, then **the first** such descendant in tree order is the label element’s labeled control."*

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu just saying and giving an average hint (no demo demonstrating the issue) . there is a label, 2 inputs (one hidden) but also an onclick event .. how is that handle from js  when mouse is pressed inside the label without or hiting the input with onclick event ;) ? looks messy to me :)

Comment: @G-Cyr, I'm also just saying your initial *"is enough to mess up the browser behavior"* suggests the markup is invalid. Multiple `<input>` elements inside one `<label>` is perfectly legal markup and would not mess up any browser. It might mess up badly written JavaScript depending on the common misconception no `<label>` should ever contain more than one `<input>`, provided the said JavaScript fails if more than one are present. But such code is rare, at least in commonly used libraries.

Comment: But let's not get side-tracked here. @DGwang: please provide a [mcve]. We can't inspect code presented to us as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that IE has a bug which causes this problem.  I found some helpful information from this site:

https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/using_images_as

The CSS fix was:

```
label img{
  pointer-events: none;
}

label{
  display: inline-block;
}
```